# Job queueing in Toast Titanium 10?

Tags: mac, video, dvd, encoding, dvd-burning

I have a bunch of .MP4 video files I'm burning to DVD-Video using Toast Titanium 10 on my MacBook Pro. Right now, I'm doing them one at a time. Because my computer is several years old, encoding video for a single DVD takes approximately six hours. I've discovered that it appears I can encode the video directly to a .toast format — however, I have yet to figure out if I can burn these directly to DVD. Also, I have quite a bit of video left to burn, and even that method would require me intervening manually to start a new encoding or burn job every six hours. Would it be possible to somehow queue up multiple DVD-Video encoding jobs at once, and have the computer work through them automatically? The actual writing to DVD disc doesn't take nearly as long, and if I had all my video encoded for me to begin with my job would be a lot quicker.

Maybe this can be accomplished with a different piece of software?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Toast doesn't have the batch features you're looking for. But that doesn't mean you can't use Toast to create your DVD (menus and all), and burn them. All you need is to have the video files in the right format, so that Toast doesn't need to re-encode them before it can create a DVD with them.

To encode your video files into MPEG-2 format, you can use software that does support batch encoding, like [ffmpegX](http://homepage.mac.com/major4/).

Once ffmpegX has encoded your video files, just drag them into Toast to create a DVD, and burn it, which, as you indicated, is a pretty quick step in this whole process.
(Make sure you disable re-encoding of video files in Toast, or it might decide to re-encode your already re-encoded video files!)